# Buttons outside the onCreate

Tags: java, android, button, oncreate

Always in my apps I added buttons in `void onCreate`, but now I'm trying to do app with more buttons (about 10). I would like to all buttons active on start app. 
In my opinion it is too much buttons to add in this onCreate and app will be starting to long.
I tried to put this:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        myMethod();
    }
})
```

out of `onCreate`

but AndroidStudio underlines `setOnClickListener` and `view`

I don't have ideas, how and where can i add button out of onCreate.

Comment: It won't take time, and also everything related to UI that is needed in the activity ,should be defined in onCreate

Comment: It's not going to cause an issue in `onCreate()` but if you want to keep that method more clean, you could create a method to do the initialization and call it from `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to overcrowd your oncreate method, then create a clicklistener outside onCreate anywhere in activity and in onCreate just set it.

onCreate :

```
    edit_a_member = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_member);
    delete_a_member = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_member);

    edit_a_member.setOnClickListener(handleClick);
    delete_a_member.setOnClickListener(handleClick);
```

clickListener:

```
 private View.OnClickListener handleClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.edit_member:
                    member_selected = EDIT_MEMBER_SELECTED;
                    callDialog();
                    break;
                case R.id.delete_member:
                    callDeleteAlert();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a separate method for your buttons in the same class, e.g.:

```
public void onCreate(...){
    //Standard setup of views or whatever you want to do here

    this.addButtons();
}

private void addButtons(){
    Button b1 = new Button("Hi");
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            myMethod();
        }   
    });

    Button b2 = new Button("Hi to you too");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            myMethod();
        }   
    });
}
```

This is an example. You can do this in soooo many ways. I feel like you should thoroughly learn Java's fundamental `Object Oriented` programming, because that's really what your question suggests you don't understand. Go follow a youtube tutorial. I always like "The New Boston"'s Java tutorial series on youtube.

PS: You can make code like this beautiful under the 'Words of wisdom': **Don't repeat yourself**

Comment: Yea, but that all depends on whether or not some buttons have duplicate functionalities. You can solve this problem in a 100 ways, all depends on what the requirements are

Comment: @RoelSrolenberg I agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do a lot of work in your onCreate but you are worried that the UI will take too long to load you can always post a delayed runnable to a handler so in the onCreate method put :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         //add your code here
     }
 },10);
```

what this will do is your UI will load then the code in your Runnable will be executed 10 milliseconds after your UI loads thus your app will not take too long to load the UI, even though in your case I doubt it would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are declaring the buttons in xml file :**


Add these properties in each button Declaration in your Xml :

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onClick"
```

And now in Activity Class create a method like this :

```
public void onClick(View v){
  switch(v.getId){
     case R.id.{buttons_id_in_xml}
        (Your Code)
        break;
        (Like for others)
    }
  }
```

**If you want to add buttons dynamically :**


Create a method to add the button like this:

```
void addButton(String buttonName, int button id){
   Button button = new Button(this);
   button.setText("Push Me");
   (add it to parent Layout of xml)
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(id){
      case id1:
      (handle )
      break;
      (like for others)
     }
   }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is:

add `implements View.OnClickListener` to

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

// declare variables
private Button mBtn1;
private Button mBtn2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    // make an instance to the btns
    mBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    // set onClickListener
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this); // with "this" you are passing the view
    mBtn2.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

// implement onClick
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // check which btn was clicked by id
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            btn1Clicked();
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            btn2Clicked();
            break;
    }
}

private void btn1Clicked() {
    // your code btn1 clicked
}

private void btn2Clicked() {
    // your code btn2 clicked
}
```

Hope this helped. Cheers!